# Correct img tag

Tags: tags, image

I'd like to ask you which img tag is right:

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/r5wwImhb.jpg">
```

or

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/r5wwImhb.jpg"/>
```

Thank you.

Comment: You need to close then tag in the first one. As it stands, the second one.

Comment: See the answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on if you are using HTML or XHTML. The first one is correct in HTML and the second one in XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

According to the first search result for `<img>` tag on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp):

> In HTML the `<img>` tag has no end tag.
>
> In XHTML the `<img>` tag must be properly closed.

Comment: This one looks fine but more knowledgeable people than me have asked me to stop using w3fools. Alternative documentation at Mozilla developer network at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Img

Comment: @kush - Thanks for the alternate resource. The OP's question does not appear to be answered on that page. There is one example that is escaped, but it does not say why.